# What is the point of using ConcurrentMap.replace in this example

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

Here's an excerpt from Java Concurrency in Practice:

```
public class DelegatingVehicleTracker {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Point> locations;
    private final Map<String, Point> unmodifiableMap;

    public DelegatingVehicleTracker(final Map<String, Point> points) {
        this.locations = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(points);
        this.unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.locations);
    }

    public Map<String, Point> getLocations() {
        return unmodifiableMap;
    }

    public Point getLocation(final String id) {
        return locations.get(id);
    }

    public void setLocation(final String id, final int x, final int y) {
        if (null == locations.replace(id, new Point(x, y))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid vehicle name: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the `setLocation` method which uses `ConcurrentMap.replace`. The JavaDoc of this method says that it's equivalent to:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
     return map.put(key, value);
} else return null;
```

except that the action is performed atomically.

What could go wrong if we don't use the atomic version. One possibility is that one thread sees that the map contains a given key and before it puts a new value for that key, another thread removes that key-value pair, but since the class in the example does not allow removals, this cannot happen.

Another possibility is that two threads attempt to replace the same key with different values. In that case one thread may not return the correct previous value but in the example we don't care about the previous value, the method `setLocation` returns `void`.

So, it seems as though the method could be rewritten without `replace`. And that is what prompted my question. In a subsequent version of the same class in the book, which almost identical to the one above, the method `setLocation` does not use `replace`, just `containsKey` and I was wondering if this could compromise thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

> the method setLocation does not use replace, just containsKey and I
>   was wondering if this could compromise thread safety.

It does, you've described it perfectly

> What could go wrong if we don't use the atomic version. One
>   possibility is that one thread sees that the map contains a given key
>   and before it puts a new value for that key, another thread removes
>   that key-value pair, but since the class in the example does not allow
>   removals, this cannot happen.

That's why the implementation of ConcurrentHashMap.replace locks the node it tries to replace

```
/**
     * Implementation for the four public remove/replace methods:
     * Replaces node value with v, conditional upon match of cv if
     * non-null.  If resulting value is null, delete.
     */
    final V replaceNode(Object key, V value, Object cv) {
        int hash = spread(key.hashCode());
        for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
            Node<K,V> f; int n, i, fh;
            if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) == 0 ||
                (f = tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash)) == null)
                break;
            else if ((fh = f.hash) == MOVED)
                tab = helpTransfer(tab, f);
            else {
                V oldVal = null;
                boolean validated = false;
                synchronized (f) {
                    if (tabAt(tab, i) == f) {
                        if (fh >= 0) {
                            validated = true;
                            for (Node<K,V> e = f, pred = null;;) {
                                K ek;
                                if (e.hash == hash &&
                                    ((ek = e.key) == key ||
                                     (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))) {
                                    V ev = e.val;
                                    if (cv == null || cv == ev ||
                                        (ev != null && cv.equals(ev))) {
                                        oldVal = ev;
                                        if (value != null)
                                            e.val = value;
                                        else if (pred != null)
                                            pred.next = e.next;
                                        else
                                            setTabAt(tab, i, e.next);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                pred = e;
                                if ((e = e.next) == null)
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (f instanceof TreeBin) {
                            validated = true;
                            TreeBin<K,V> t = (TreeBin<K,V>)f;
                            TreeNode<K,V> r, p;
                            if ((r = t.root) != null &&
                                (p = r.findTreeNode(hash, key, null)) != null) {
                                V pv = p.val;
                                if (cv == null || cv == pv ||
                                    (pv != null && cv.equals(pv))) {
                                    oldVal = pv;
                                    if (value != null)
                                        p.val = value;
                                    else if (t.removeTreeNode(p))
                                        setTabAt(tab, i, untreeify(t.first));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (validated) {
                    if (oldVal != null) {
                        if (value == null)
                            addCount(-1L, -1);
                        return oldVal;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> What could go wrong if we don't use the atomic version

Nothing.

It's stylistic. You could implement the `setLocation` method whatever way you want, but it just so happens that `replace` is a nice way to ensure that you only insert if the given location exists in the map.

> In a subsequent version of the same class in the book, which almost identical to the one above, the method setLocation does not use replace, just containsKey and I was wondering if this could compromise thread safety.

It does not compromise thread safety. The assertion that the key is contained in the map cannot change in a concurrent write because given that the key is present, it will not suddenly be removed, and given that it is not present, nothing will be done.

The author decided to use contains key because the second example uses a mutable point rather than an immutable point. Recall that JCIP was written for Java 5 and such methods as `computeIfPresent` did not exist at the time. Therefore, the author must obtain the object it self in order to modify it. Thread safety will therefore be delegated to the mutable point rather than the vehicle tracker itself.